# XML doc won't validate to XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to learn XML, and I found an XML Schema online, to which I've tried making an instance document. For some reason which I just don't get, my document won't validate to the schema. Can someone point out my mistake?

> Error message: Cause: Error on line 2: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the
>   declaration of element 'movies'.

**Document**:

```
<movies>
    <movie>
        <title>The Revenant</title>
        <length>120</length>
        <year>2015</year>
        <cast>
            <role ref="Lead">
            </role>
        </cast>
    </movie>
    <person id="Leo">
        <name>Leonardo DiCaprio</name>
        <birth>1982-12-13</birth>
    </person>
</movies>
```

**Schema**:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:m="http://movies.example"
    targetNamespace="http://movies.example"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

<element name="movies">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="m:movie" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <element ref="m:person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <unique name="movies-unique">
        <selector xpath="m:movie"/>
        <field xpath="m:title"/>
        <field xpath="m:year"/>
    </unique>
    <key name="cast-key">
        <selector xpath="m:person|m:star"/>
        <field xpath="@id"/>
    </key>
    <keyref refer="m:cast-key" name="cast-keyref">
        <selector xpath=".//m:role"/>
        <field xpath="@ref"/>
    </keyref>
</element>

<element name="movie">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="title" type="string"/>
            <element name="length" type="nonNegativeInteger"/>
            <element name="year" type="gYear"/>
            <element name="cast">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <element name="role">
                            <complexType mixed="true">
                                <attribute name="ref" type="NCName"/>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>

<element name="person" type="m:personType"/>

<complexType name="personType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="string"/>
        <element name="birth" type="date"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="id" type="NCName"/>
</complexType>

<element name="star" substitutionGroup="m:person">
    <complexType>
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="m:personType">
                <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <element name="award" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</element>

</schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following updated XML will validate successfully against your XSD:**

```
<movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://movies.example"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://movies.example try.xsd">
  <movie>
    <title>The Revenant</title>
    <length>120</length>
    <year>2015</year>
    <cast>
      <role ref="Leo"/>
    </cast>
  </movie>
  <person id="Leo">
    <name>Leonardo DiCaprio</name>
    <birth>1982-12-13</birth>
  </person>
</movies>
```

**Updates required**:

1. Added default namespace (`xmlns="http://movies.example"`) to match
   the `targetNamespace` of the XSD.
2. Changed `role/@ref` value to `"Leo"` to satisify the `cast-keyref`
   `key` constraint of the XSD.

Answer (score -1):

It may be worth noting that the xsi:schemaLocation attribute is not normally required, although XMLSpy and other tools often insert it. The only *required* change is to add the default namespace declaration:

```
<movies xmlns="http://movies.example">
  <movie>
    <title>The Revenant</title>
    <length>120</length>
    <year>2015</year>
    <cast>
      <role ref="Leo"/>
    </cast>
  </movie>
  <person id="Leo">
    <name>Leonardo DiCaprio</name>
    <birth>1982-12-13</birth>
  </person>
</movies>
```

( The xsi:schemaLocation *might* still be required in order to make the OP's XML tool happy )

Comment: (a) No one said that `xsi:schemaLocation` is required; (b) Your statement that "The *only* required change is to add the default namespace declaration" is incorrect; as I've [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35304906/290085), there are **two** updates required.